# Field of a model is not persisted

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm currently working on a small Golf app for some friends of mine. A feature of the app is to discover Courses on the map, save them in SwiftData and then add a "scheme" to the course in order to track your games properly. The last part, adding schemes, is the place where I hit a roadblock, and I'm at a loss at what to do.

These are the Datatypes I use:

```swift
struct HoleModel : Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var holeNumber : Int
    var par : Int
    var holeDistance : Int
    
    init(holeNumber: Int, par: Int, holeDistance: Int) {
        self.holeNumber = holeNumber
        self.par = par
        self.holeDistance = holeDistance
    }
}

@Model
final class CourseSchemeModel {
    /* TODO: curate who created the model */
    
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var longitude: Double
    var latitude: Double
    var url: String
    var holes: [HoleModel]
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, longitude: Double, latitude: Double, url: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.url = url
        holes = []
    }
}
```

The CourseSchemeModel is created when bookmarking a course on the map. Through a form, I can then enter the relevant information for each of a course's holes. When I want to save a a Scheme, I'm showing a confirmation dialogue. I've stripped all that complexity in testing though, and moved the logic into the view where I query the data:

```swift
struct DemoView {
    @Query courses: [CourseSchemeModel]

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
    
    func updateHoles(id: Int, holes: [HoleModel]) {
        var course = courses.where {course in course.id == id}
        course.name = "xyz"   //this works perfectly
        course.holes = holes  //this does not
    }
}
```

I really don't know why the changes would not come through. What I've tried so far:

- I've verified that the data I gather is correct.
- I've added a method to the Model Class to try to manipulate the data 'from within'
- I've made sure that the functions are called and that the data is passed along correctly
- I've searched online for this problem and could not find something comparable
- I've reset the simulator
- I've reduced the complexity of the View (the results of which I showed above)

Also, there is no error showing in the console.
Because SwiftData is so new, I feel incapable of finding good resources except the WWDC and some videos that more or less copy the session's demo project.

Because of the nature of the error, however, I feel like something with how I defined the HoleModel struct in itself is the reason why this field is not updated.

Comment: In your code I see that you're assigning `[HoleSchemeModel]` to `CourseSchemeModel`'s holes property that is of type `[HoleModel]`. What's going on?

Comment: @Timmy I've editet my original Post. I've introduced that error myself when writing this post.

Comment: it should be `func updateHoles(id: Int, holes: [HoleModel])`

Comment: You are of course completely correct.

Comment: does it work now?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've introduced these errors when writing this post.

Comment: Try adding the other end of the relationshop as a property as well to HoleModel. `let courseScheme: CourseSchemeModel?` if it is a one-to-many relationship or `let courseSchemes: [CourseSchemeModel]` if it is a many-to-many relationship

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's a good Idea. I've just got it to run properly and came back to answer my question. I will add that field later though, and transform the HoleModel to  a SwiftData Model as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions so far, I really appreciate that. Shortly after posting it, I fixed it. Better yet, xcode fixed it for me: After "Clean Build Files" it now runs as expected.
Your guess is as good as mine, although I suspect that me removing a model from the schema earlier might have destroyed something under the hood.

I'm sorry for posting this question in the first place. Cleaning the build files should have been one of my first steps.

Comment: I'll be closing this issue as soon as possible, which is in two days